# Prove $\omega_1$ is first countable

Tags: general-topology, ordinals, first-countable

Given a well order $(W,\le)$, where W is uncountable, and $\omega_1:= \{x\in W:$ only countably many $y \in X$ s.t. $y \le x\}$, prove $\omega_1$ is first countable.

I saw a proof saying that $\{(a,x]: a < x\}$ is a local basis at $x$, if $x$ is not the least element of $\omega_1$, but I haven't figured out why each element of the local basis is open.

Comment: Can you describe a neighbourhood basis of $x \in \omega_1$?

Comment: That is what confuses me. I saw a proof saying that {(a,x]: a $\lt$ x} is a local basis at x, but I haven't figured out why each element of the local basis is open.

Comment: Perhaps add what confuses you to the actual question.

Comment: Consider the set $\{ b \in W : x < b\}$. $W$ is a well-order, so either it is empty, or ...

Comment: @Daniel Fishcher: has a least element..

Comment: Right. Call it $y$. Then $(a,x] = (a,y)$.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer: Oh, I see, thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: Given any $y\in\omega_1,$ let $S(y)$ be the least element of $\omega_1$ greater than $y.$ (You may need to prove that such an element exists.) Now, consider the set of intervals $\bigl(x,S(y)\bigr)$ with $x<y$ if $y$ is a non-least element of $\omega_1.$ On the other hand, if $y$ *is* the least element of $\omega_1,$ then $\{y\}$ is open (why?), and so we can conclude that...?

Comment: I see, but I saw another proof claiming that  That is what confuses me. I saw a proof saying that {(a,x]: a < x} is a local basis at x, if x is non-least element of $\omega_1$, but I don't know why each (a,x] is open. It is clear that (x,S(y)) is open.

Comment: The kicker is that $(a,x]=\bigl(a,S(x)\bigr)$--using the notation from my answer--as is readily shown with a double-inclusion proof. I simply wrote it the way I did in order to make openness more clear. The approach is really no different. Does that clear things up for you?

Comment: Yes, I get it. Thank you very much.